# Rails 4. Migrating (some) legacy DB data from old db to rails existing DataBase

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, dump, legacy

I have a task to import old data from old DB to new Rails app. Old program was created in Delphi and is outdated so customer decided create rails app for replacing it. I have dump file, and I am creating local MySQL db now and inserting there data for last 8 years (mysql is working for over an hour already) :)

Now I am not sure about the way old data should be imported. The problem is that old db tables and columns are named differently from what I have in my App and there are many of unused and unneeded columns/tables there. So I need select only some of them and insert into App DB. Could You please suggest the best solution for this case?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust old db to rails app and work with it

Let's imagine you have old DB with the following table `old_posts`

```
old_posts
________________________________________
sysid | name         | description      |
_______________________________________
      |              |                  |
1     | The best post| Some description |
_______________________________________
      |              |                  |
2     | Another  post| Another descrip  |
________________________________________
```

In rails you can define `table_name` with
More information in doc:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name

Also you can redifine attributes with `alias_attribute`
More information in doc:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_attribute

To change primary key `primary_key`
More information in doc:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key-3D

The example will be seems as

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'sysid'
  self.table_name  = 'old_posts`

  alias_attribute :name, :title
  alias_attribute :description, :content
end
```

Then you can invoke:

```
p = Post.find(1)
p.title #= >  The best post
```

Also you can use legacy database separately from rails app database

http://ilikestuffblog.com/2012/09/21/establishing-a-connection-to-a-non-default-database-in-rails-3-2-2/

Comment: I didn't understand it from the first time, but after thinking it over I got the idea and that worked well. Thanks!